# Python ValueError from np.where create flag based on one condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

If the city has been mentioned in `cities_specific` I would like to create a flag in the `cities_all` data. It's just a minimal example and in reality I would like to create multiple of these flags based on multiple data frames. That's why I tried to solve it with `isin` instead of a join.

However, I am running into  `ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (7)`.

```
# import packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# create minimal data 
cities_specific = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['Melbourne', 'Cairns', 'Sydney'],
                       'n': [10, 4, 8]})
cities_all = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['Vancouver', 'Melbourne', 'Athen', 'Vienna', 'Cairns',
                                    'Berlin', 'Sydney'],
                          'inhabitants': [675218, 5000000, 664046, 1897000, 150041, 3769000, 5312000]})


# get value error
# how can this be solved differently?
cities_all.assign(in_cities_specific=np.where(cities_specific.city.isin(cities_all.city), '1', '0'))


# that's the solution I would like to get
expected_solution = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['Vancouver', 'Melbourne', 'Athen', 'Vienna', 'Cairns',
                                    'Berlin', 'Sydney'],
                          'inhabitants': [675218, 5000000, 664046, 1897000, 150041, 3769000, 5312000],
                          'in_cities': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]})
```

Comment: I think you have you logic wrong,  `cities_all.assign(in_cities_specific=np.where(cities_all.city.isin(cities_specific.city), '1', '0'))
` is correct.  You wanna know if the city in the row is in **city_specific**

Comment: What `ValueError`?  Give full information when asking questions like this.  My guess is you have a "Ambiguity" error, trying to do some sort of logical operation on Series inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are changing the position in the condition.
Here you have some alternatives:

```py
cities_all.assign(
     in_cities_specific=np.where(cities_all.city.isin(cities_specific.city), '1', '0')
)
```

or

```py
cities_all["in_cities_specific"] =  
                    cities_all["city"].isin(cities_specific["city"]).astype(int).astype(str)
```

or

```py
condlist = [cities_all["city"].isin(cities_specific["city"])]
choicelist = ["1"]
cities_all["in_cities_specific"] = np.select(condlist, choicelist,default="0")
```